# NS&I website asking for cookie permision on every page despite having accepted all cookies!

Tags: cookie

nsandi.com warns about cookies on every single page I visit, despite the fact that I have Accepted All Cookies on previous pages.

I flagged this to NS&I, but they were less than helpful.

*The reason for this is we don't cater for Linux based systems, to successfully use our website please use Windows, android, IOS or MacOS.*

Apparently it's my fault for using the wrong OS!

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, laptop and Firefox (117.0 (64-bit)) - at least they support my choice of browser.

Is there anything that can be done at my end to resolve this?

If so what?

Comment: I’d try with a different browser?

Comment: Check your browser settings - are you configured to save cookies in somewhere writable?

Comment: Will - tried Opera and it works fine, maybe it's a browser issue

Comment: waltinator - I have not knowingly done anything to change where cookies are stored. I have deleted all nsandi.com cookies and tried again but no joy

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.
Stripped out all nsandi cookies, then launched their site and opted into functional and performance cookies, opted out of others and it now works OK.
Tried to compare cookies on FireFox vs Opera, but whereas I can see the individual cookies in Opera I can't see the same level of detail in FF.
Appears to be a browser rather than Ubuntu issue.